# How to assign use this in a construct

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im a bit of a beginner when it comes to javascript constructs. Im trying in jquery, but not with much success. The following is a reduces version of my code:

```
var field1 = {
        fieldId:"#field1",
        field:"",
        init:function(){
            this.field = this;
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:'some/url/to/get/values/from',
                cache:false,
                success: function(data){
                    alert(field.fieldId);
                }
            }); 
        }
};
field1.init();
```

Basically i want to be able to print out field.fieldid inside the success event but i end up with something most definetly not expected. I would hate having to write field1.field.fieldid everytime also since that would ruin when i figure out how to use extends and similar things.

Can anyone help me get "#field1" out when i do the alert(field.fieldId) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case of [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html). The simplest answer in your case is a local variable in your init function:

```
var field1 = {
        fieldId:"#field1",
        field:"",
        init:function(){
            var self = this;                      // <=== change here
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:'some/url/to/get/values/from',
                    cache:false,
                success: function(data){
                    alert(self.fieldId);          // <=== and here
                }
            }); 
        }
};
field1.init();
```

Or alternately, use the `context` argument of the [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function:

```
var field1 = {
        fieldId:"#field1",
        field:"",
        init:function(){
                                                  // <=== change here (no `this.field = this;`)
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:'some/url/to/get/values/from',
                cache:false,
                context: this,                    // <=== and here
                success: function(data){
                    alert(this.fieldId);          // <=== and here
                }
            }); 
        }
};
field1.init();
```

Basically, in JavaScript, the value of `this` during a function call is defined entirely by *how a function is called*, not where it's defined as in some other languages (C++, Java, C#, ...). When jQuery calls the `success` callback of the `ajax` function, it has to set `this` to something. By default, it sets it to an object representing the settings of the ajax call, but using `context` you can tell jQuery to set it to something else, allowing you to use `this` within the callback to mean the same thing as `this` when you call `ajax`.

The first solution takes advantage of the fact that the `success` callback is a *closure* over the context of the call to `init` (don't worry, [closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)), and so by creating a variable (`self`) and giving it the value of `this`, we can reliably refer to the object via `self` within the closure (the `success` callback).

---

Ways in which `this` is set in JavaScript:

1. When you call a function by getting the function reference from an object property as part of the same expression as the call, `this` within the function call will be the object from which you got the property. So given:

   ```
   var obj = {
       firstName: "Fred",
       speak: function(msg) {
           alert(this.firstName + " says " + msg);
       }
   };
   ```

   then

   ```
   obj.speak("hi");   // alerts "Fred says hi", because `this = obj` within the call
   ```

   Note that it has to be part of the same expression as the call. This does *not* work:

   ```
   var s = obj.speak; // Getting a reference to `obj`'s `speak`
   s("hi");           // alerts "undefined says hi", because `this` is not
                      // `obj` during the call
   ```
2. Using `call` or `apply`. These are features of all JavaScript functions. They let you call the function and explicitly set what `this` will be during the call. So given the `obj` above:

   ```
   var s = obj.speak; // Getting a reference to `obj`'s `speak`
   s.call(obj, "hi"); // alerts "Fred says hi", we explicitly made `this = obj`
                      // within the call
   ```

   The only difference between `call` and `apply` is that when you use `call`, if you want to pass arguments to the function, you include them as discrete arguments to `call` as above (note we just passed `"hi"` as a second argument to `call`, and `call` passed it on as the first argument to the function). With `apply`, rather than an unlimited number of discrete arguments, the second argument is an *array* of arguments to pass to the function.

   ```
   // Example 1: Passing no arguments, no difference.
   // These calls do the same thing.
   func.call(obj);
   func.apply(obj);

   // Example 2: Passing one argument (these calls do the same thing).
   func.call(obj, arg);
   func.apply(obj, [arg]); // note that it's in an array

   // Example 3: Passing two arguments (these calls do the same thing).
   func.call(obj, arg1, arg2);
   func.apply(obj, [arg1, arg2]); // Again, the args are in an array
   ```

Comment: Thank you soo much this was really helpfull,after messing about with "this" for some time you loose hope when you dont know what you are looking for :)

Comment: What if i add complexity by having two functions init and also add draw...  init calls draw, but then i need to keep setting self or this in the context, is there an easy way to set a variable to be avaiable across the whole of field1 ?